# Open link in new private window on iPad with safari

Tags: safari, ipad, productivity

In order to avoid cluttering my history and such I often want to quickly open links in a private window. This is in the middle of a non private session.

How I do this in Chrome:

1. Long press link
2. Open in incognito tab

Is there a quick way to do this in Safari  on iPad as well?

So far the quickest path I found is as follows:

1. Long press link
2. Copy
3. Long press tab list
4. New private tab
5. Long press address bar
6. Paste and go

Not only is this a long process, it also flushes my clipboard which can mean extra time lost.

I know there are ways to work around this, like using a different browser, but I just wonder if there is a way to do this in safari.

Comment: @fsb That's for macOS, holding option doesn't work for the context menu on iPadOS.

Comment: I think @grg replied to someone who mentioned a potential solution, but to avoid confusion: I am indeed on the latest version of iPadOS